# Procedure for evaluating the hypergeometric series $_2F_1\left\{\frac{v+2}{2},\frac{v+3}{2};v+1;z\right\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I'm trying to work out the procedure to get the following hypergeometric series into a simpler form, for all postive integer $v$:
$$ _2F_1\left\{\frac{v+2}{2},\frac{v+3}{2};v+1;z\right\}$$

For example, plugging this into Wolfram Alpha gives for $v$ = 1,
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{3/2}}$$
for $v$ = 2,
$$\frac{4 (2 \sqrt{1-z} \,(z-1)-3 z+2)}{3 \sqrt{1-z}\, (z-1) z^2}$$
for $v$ = 3,
$$-\frac{2 (3 z^2+4 (2 \sqrt{1-z}-3) z-8 \sqrt{1-z}+8)}{(1-z)^{3/2} z^3}$$
and so on.

I'm guessing a transformation is repeatedly applied until a terminating form of the hypergeometric series is obtained. For $v$ = 1, applying Euler's transformation, 
$$_2F_1 (a,b;c;z) =
(1-z)^{c-a-b}{}_2F_1 (c-a, c-b;c ; z)$$
gives the correct form; however, I cant work out what is used for $v$ = 2 and higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Mathematica,

$$
_2F_1\left(\frac{v+2}{2},\frac{v+3}{2};v+1;z\right) = \frac{2^v \left(1+\sqrt{1-z}\right)^{-v} \left(1+v \sqrt{1-z}\right)}{(1+v) (1-z)^{3/2}}.
$$

I would be surprised if this was not known, especially considering how close it is to the [known cases](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_556.htm) $_2F_1(a,a+1/2;2a+1;z)$ and $_2F_1(a,a+1/2;2a;z)$.  Indeed, if $b=(v+2)/2$ and $c = (v-1)/2$ then

$$\begin{align}
_2F_1\left(\frac{v+2}{2},\frac{v+3}{2};v+1;z\right) &= {}_2F_1\left(b,b+\frac{1}{2};2b-1;z\right) \\
       &= (1-z)^{-3/2} {}_2F_1\left(c,c+\frac{1}{2};2c+2;z\right).
\end{align}$$

The DLMF gives [Prudnikov et al. (1990, pp. 468–488)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/bib/P#bib1887) as a reference for elementary representations, which I'll check out from the library tomorrow.

---

**Edit.**

With a little coaxing, Mathematica seems able to evaluate 
$$
_2F_1\left(\frac{v+u}{2},\frac{v+u+1}{2};v+1;z\right)
$$

for all nonnegative integer $u$ through the use of the integral representation

$$
_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\,\Gamma(c-b)} \int_0^1 \frac{t^{b-1} (1-t)^{c-b-1}}{(1-t z)^a}\,dt.
$$

For **even** $u$ we can evaluate it using the code

```
u=2 n;
a=(v+u)/2;
b=(v+u+1)/2;
c=v+1;
Expand[Integrate[t^(b-1) (1-t)^(c-b-1)/(1-t z)^a,{t,0,1},
    Assumptions->Re[v]>u-1&&Re[z]<=1] 
  Gamma[c]/(Gamma[b] Gamma[c-b])]//FullSimplify
```

One such example is

$$\begin{align}
&_2F_1\left(\frac{v+4}{2},\frac{v+5}{2};v+1;z\right) \\
&\qquad= \frac{2^v v^2 \left(1+\sqrt{1-z}\right)^{-v} \Gamma(v+1) \left(v (1-z)^{3/2}-6 (z-1)\right)}{(1-z)^{7/2} \Gamma(v+4)} \\
&\hspace{2cm} + \frac{2^v \left(1+\sqrt{1-z}\right)^{-v} \Gamma(v+1) \left(6 + 9 z+v \sqrt{1-z} (11+4 z)\right)}{(1-z)^{7/2} \Gamma(v+4)}.
\end{align}$$

For **odd** $u$ we can reduce it back to the even case (sort of) by using the identity

$$\begin{align}
&{}_2F_1\left(\frac{v+u}{2},\frac{v+u+1}{2};v+1;z\right) \\
&\qquad = \frac{2 v {}_2F_1\left(\frac{v+u-1}{2},\frac{v+u}{2},v,z\right)-(v-u+1) {}_2F_1\left(\frac{v+u-1}{2},\frac{v+u}{2},v+1,z\right)}{v+u-1},
\end{align}$$

which is courtesy of Mathematica and is probably some combination of [Gauss' relations for the contiguous hypergeometric functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_558.htm).

The code is thus

```
u=2 n+1;
a=(v+u-1)/2;
b=(v+u)/2;
c1=v;
c2=v+1;
Expand[
  (2 v Integrate[t^(b-1) (1-t)^(c1-b-1)/(1-t z)^a,{t,0,1},
        Assumptions->Re[v]>u+1&&Re[z]<=1] 
      Gamma[c1]/(Gamma[b] Gamma[c1-b])
   -(v-u+1) Integrate[t^(b-1) (1-t)^(c2-b-1)/(1-t z)^a,{t,0,1},
        Assumptions->Re[v]>u-1&&Re[z]<=1] 
      Gamma[c2]/(Gamma[b] Gamma[c2-b]))/(v+u-1)]//FullSimplify
```

And an example,

$$\begin{align}
&{}_2F_1\left(\frac{v+3}{2},\frac{v+4}{2};v+1;z\right) \\
&\qquad = \frac{2^v v \left(1+\sqrt{1-z}\right)^{-v} \Gamma(v+1) \left(3\sqrt{1-z} + v(1-z)\right)}{(1-z)^{5/2} \Gamma(v+3)} \\
&\hspace{2cm} + \frac{2^v \left(1+\sqrt{1-z}\right)^{-v} \Gamma(v+1) \left(2+z\right)}{(1-z)^{5/2} \Gamma(v+3)}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. I just put it into Wolfram Alpha and got a less concise form, will try to get a hold of Mathematica. Before now I had been finding it with values substituted for v. To give some background I'm looking at actually is 6.621 - 1. Gradshteyn and Rhyzik (page 699) which uses $$_2F_1\left(\frac{v+u}{2},\frac{v+u+1}{2};v+1;-\frac{\beta^2}{\alpha^2}\right)$$ for $u$ = 2. Might need to find an expression for a higher value of $u$ later.

Comment: @geometrikal, I have added a bit on calculating that expression for higher values of $u$.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and the code for Mathematica. That will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question with this post:

[Tables of Hypergeometric Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41935/tables-of-hypergeometric-functions)

There is a link to a paper that describes a method for performing the transformations. The method is quite complicated and not worth rewriting here. Apparently the python package sympy has a function "hyperexpand" that can work it out.

Update:

Thanks again to Antonio for the hint to start from a known form. I've worked out the process:
Substituting $a = v/2$ we get
$$ _2F_1\left\{\frac{v+2}{2},\frac{v+3}{2};v+1;z\right\} = \,_2F_1\left\{a+1,a+\frac{3}{2};2a+1;z\right\} $$
Since [[1]](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_556.htm),
$$ _2F_1\left\{a,a+\frac{1}{2};2a+1;z\right\} = 2^{2a}(1 + \sqrt{1-z})^{-2a} $$
and [[2]](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=hypergeometric%20function%20representations&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcybertester.com%2Fdata%2Fissac96.pdf&ei=ApC4T5G-B5ChiAePs63vCA&usg=AFQjCNHDwGH1kltWxHFsauPgLehYTJrR2A),

$$ _2F_1\{a_1 + 1,a_2;b;z\} = \left(\frac{z}{a_1}\frac{d}{dz} + 1\right) \,_2F_1\{a_1, a_2;b;z\}, $$
$$ _2F_1\{a_1,a_2+1;b;z\} = \left(\frac{z}{a_2}\frac{d}{dz} + 1\right) \,_2F_1\{a_1, a_2;b;z\}, $$

then,
$$ _2F_1\left\{a+1,a+\frac{3}{2};2a+1;z\right\}  = \left(\frac{z}{a_1}\frac{d}{dz} + 1\right)\left(\frac{z}{a_2}\frac{d}{dz} + 1\right)\left(2^{2a}(1 + \sqrt{1-z})^{-2a}\right).$$

The rest follows by doing the differentiation and substuting back $v/2 = a$, and gives the same result as described in Antonio's answer.

Comment: Nice work on figuring out a proper derivation!